# grab one side of an equation

Tags: map

Is there a simple way to grab or reference one side of an equation?

Minimal example of what I mean:

```
    eq = x^2==3x
    (*Pseudo Code*)
    in: Grab_lefthandside(eq)
    out: x^2
```

Comment: `eq[[1]]` or `First@eq`

Comment: tested and worked, tyvm. So it is internally an array...?

Comment: Check `FullForm[eq]`.

Comment: @AskingQuestions. *Everything* (basically) in *Mathematica* is an expression of which you can take `Part`s. `Sin[x][[1]] gives `x`, for instance. Even `Graphics` objects: look at `FullForm[Plot[x, {x, 0, 1}]]`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can change Equal to List and you will have the list of left and right hand sides of the equation.

```
First[List @@ (x^2 == 3 x)]
```

Comment: `Part`, `First`, `Last`, etc. operate on expressions not just a `List`. There is no need to convert to a `List` to use them. Try `f[a, b, c] // First`

Comment: That is true. However, I wanted to show how one can extract and manipulate all the objects in an expression.